# Android: Tabbed Layout or Android Tabs without having an Action Bar?

Tags: android, xml, layout, tabs, themes

So I created my app to have tabs on the action bar which direct to three fragment windows. I decided to change the theme of the app to `"@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"` and suddenely my app started crashing with a nullpointer exception. After sometime I realized that the theme change, which disabled the action bar might have caused this.

Is there a way to implement tabbed layout without an action bar? A custom action bar? I badly want to use that theme. OR is there a way to customize the action bar: change the color or add custom icons and search function to make it more visually appealing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to implement tabbed layout without an action bar?

Use `ViewPager` and any one of several tabbed indicators, such as `PagerTabStrip`, the `TabPageIndicator` from the ViewPagerIndicator library, `PagerSlidingTabStrip`, etc.

Or, use `FragmentTabHost`.

> is there a way to customize the action bar: change the color or add custom icons and search function to make it more visually appealing?

You are responsible for your own icons, so if you do not like your icons, talk to yourself about having yourself come up with better ones.

You can change the color of the action bar via a custom theme, such as one you might set up with Jeff Gilfelt's [Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/). Or, switch to using the `appcompat-v7` edition of the action bar (with `ActionBarActivity`) and you can use a simpler custom theme where you just set some tint values.

Answer (score 0):

as you have not provided code here i think you are using API 21 or less.. so you should change theme of your android application.
change styles.xml file as follows

```
 <resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">

</style>
```